# React native paper theming v3 has tint around IconButtons

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I updated my theming from version 2 to version 3, but now I have an annoying tint around all my IconButtons (as well as around the navigation icons).
I know I can remove the tint by adding a variable to the IconButton `containerColor` and setting it to "transparant", but I was hoping there is a less manual labor-intensive option..

[image: tint around IconButtons on iPhone simulator]

```
const defaultTheme = isDarkMode ? MD3DarkTheme : MD3LightTheme;
const paperTheme = {
  ...defaultTheme,
  //version: 2, // default is version 3
  roundness: 5,
  colors: {
    ...defaultTheme.colors,
    primary: '#0481b8',
    accent: '#0481b8',
    onPrimary: 'white',
    secondary: '#0481b8',
    onSecondary: 'white',
    primaryContainer: '#0481b8',
    onPrimaryContainer: '#0481b8',
    secondaryContainer: '#0481b8',
    onSecondaryContainer: 'white',
    tertiary: '#159BD6',
    tertiaryContainer: '#0481b8',
    onTertiary: 'white',
    background: '#f6f6f6',
    backdrop: 'red',
    text: '#000000',

    //accent: 'green',
    elevation: {
      level0: 'white',
      level1: 'white',
      level2: 'white',
      level3: 'white',
      level4: 'white',
      level5: 'white',
    },
  },
};
```